# Set null object to a value

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4, oop, model-view-controller

I need to be able to edit a user in the database after the user has been and has no value for city. 
Every thing works and can be edited but I can not edit the city.

```
thisuser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
thisuser.LastName = user.LastName;
thisuser.UserName = user.UserName;
thisuser.Password = user.Password;
if (thisuser.Address != null)
{
   thisuser.Address.City = user.Address.City;
}
else if (thisuser.Address == null) !I need help here
{

}
```

Comment: Is this using Entity Framework, Linq-2-Sql, anything? Are these just custom pocos?

Comment: It's using Entity Framework @JoelEtherton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is using an ORM data layer of some kind you simply need to create the object, set its values and then add it to the parent object.

```
thisuser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
thisuser.LastName = user.LastName;
thisuser.UserName = user.UserName;
thisuser.Password = user.Password;

if (thisuser.Address == null)
{
    thisuser.Address = new Address();   // Make sure this is the type 
                                        // that Address should be
                                        // This also assumes that Address is 1 to 1
}

thisuser.Address.City = user.Address.City;
```

If the Address property is a navigation property that can contain multiple addresses, then you'll need to select the appropriate address before setting the city, and instead of a simple assignment as above you'll need to add it to the sequence.